# JQuery UI resize issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

Simple situation - two div's and one div which is the box.
The outer div is scrollable. 
The div.box is resizable (w,e). 
When i try to resize from Right to Left the div.box is collapsed to width:0px.

Live example here: [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sdoichev/4awJm)

I already read everything about jquery-ui resizable, but can't find the solution for me.
I'll appreciate any help.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-scroll">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-scroll {
    display:block;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
    border:1px solid #666;
}
.container {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
    padding:20px 0;    
    background-color:#eee;
}
.box {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:1000px;
    left:0;
    /*right:0;    */
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.box').resizable({
    containment: 'parent',
    handles: 'w, e',
    grid: [10,10]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing your containment call fixes the issue and it's redundant either way as far as I can see:

```
$('.box').resizable({
    handles: 'w, e',
    grid: [10,10]
});
```

*EDIT*

Taking into account your comment then, your best bet is probably to use the 'maxWidth' option and set this to the width of your container like so (using the width in the fiddle as an example).

```
$('.box').resizable({
    maxWidth: 1000,
    handles: 'w, e',
    grid: [10,10]
});
```

Comment: Yes. Removing the 'containment' solve the problem with unexpected collapsing. But I need a 'containment' because I want to keep div.box not to exceeds borders of div.container (That is mandatory!).

Comment: Ok see updated answer, this should allow for the functionality you mentioned.

Comment: Yep you right again, but maxWidth does't protected div.box to exceeds borders of div.container. For example you can try first to resize left side then resize right side of div.box. I start to think that this is a major issue of jquery-ui resizable. Probably resizable don't calculate containment accurately when some of the parents is scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround with parasite div.box-wrap, it's not perfect, but is kind of a solution.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-scroll">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box-wrapper">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#fc3;
}
```

The idea is: the parent container is to be in normal flow rendering, not an absolute or relative positioned.
Updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/sdoichev/Fac9m/

For now it will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine when I removed the containment. I think the containment was stopping it from resizing.
http://jsfiddle.net/4awJm/15/

```js
$('.box').resizable({
    
 handles: 'w, e',
    grid: [50,10]
});
```

```css
.container-scroll {
    display:block;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
    border:1px solid #666;
}
.container {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:100px;
    padding:20px 0;    
    background-color:#eee;
}
.box {
    display:block;
    
    left:0;
    right:0;    
    height:50px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-scroll">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```